# Why a function that has a return type but doesn't return anything doesn't fail compilation?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

Consider the following example, compiled with g++ 5.4 (only):

```
#include <iostream>

int foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo();
    return 0;
}
```

`foo()` doesn't have any `return` statement, the code compiles and the function will return an unknown value, same will happen when return type is a pointer - which might cause a segmentation fault.

Why there is no error/warning when compiling such a function?

Is it because of the C++ standard or an issue to implement it?

Comment: Because the C++ standard says that the behaviour is undefined.   When behaviour is undefined, no diagnostic is required.   However, most modern compilers CAN detect such cases - but are configured not to give such diagnostics by default.  Look up options for your compiler to enable more warnings and other diagnostics.   The reason it is undefined behaviour according to the standard is that not all cases can be readily detected (in code more complicated than yours) and there is a potential of false positives.

Comment: The compiler is able to detect it, if you enable the warning (`-Wreturn-type` option), but it's not enabled by default for GCC version 5.4. It's not enable by default until version 8.1.

Comment: Why no warning/error ? Because you forgot to use options `-Wall -Werror`, I encourage you to *always* use at least `-Wall`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why there is no error ... when compiling such a function?

Because the program is well-formed. Compilers are required to successfully compile all well-formed programs.

> Why there is no ... warning when compiling such a function?

The standard does not require there to be a warning. Old versions of GCC only warn about mistakes like this if you ask the compiler to do so. GCC 8 enabled this particular warning by default.

> and the function will return an unknown value

Not quite. The behaviour of the program is undefined if the execution reaches the end of the non-void function without a return, so that may or might not happen.

Note that the function would actually have well defined behaviour in case the stream insertion operator happened to throw or terminated the program. We know that stream insertion is not guaranteed to throw nor to terminate the program, and that it would actually be quite surprising. But the compiler cannot make that kind of generalisations.

Comment: Can a program be both well-formed, and have UB?

Comment: @cigien Yes. UB and well-formedness are distinct concepts. Well-formed is defined as *"C++ program constructed according to the syntax rules, diagnosable semantic rules, and the one-definition rule"*.

Comment: Oof, thanks. I can never seem to wrap my head around all the distinctions :(

Comment: @cigien rough rule of thumb: ill-formed -> diagnostic at compile time (except when not diagnosable); UB -> anything or nothing at runtime.

Comment: That bit I think i get actually. It's additional things like well-formed, ifndr, etc, that I still trip over. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @cigien difference between UB and IFNDR is that latter is ill-formed and therefore compiler is not required to succesfully compile.

Comment: Oh, but compilers are *required* to compile a well-formed program, even if it has UB?

Comment: @cigien Yes. To be exact: *'a conforming implementation shall, within its resource limits, accept and correctly execute [2] that program. ; [2] “Correct execution” can include undefined behavior'*

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot more sense. Thanks for the clarification, I appreciate it.

Comment: @eerorika Why is it considered well-formed? I have a function that it's signature tells it will return something, but doesn't return anything, on the other hand a function with return type `void` will fail compilation if I'll try to use the `return` statement.

Comment: @joepol Because no rule in the language says that a function declared to return something must have a return statement. There is a rule saying that a function returning void must not have a non-empty return statement.

Comment: @eerorika Is there a reasoning for not having such a rule? After all If I declare a function to have a return type, If I don't return anything or exit the function in some other way (`exit()`, throw exception, etc..) I consider it to be an error.

Comment: @joepol I don't know what is the reasoning behind that choice. There may exist some legacy backwards compatibility issue that I am not aware of. Advantage of not having such rule is that having fewer rules makes the language simpler to specify and implement. If such rule existed, it couldn't detect all mistakes anyway because for example a function `int foo() { if(false) return 42; }` has a return statement, but has undefined behaviour regardless.

Answer (score 4):

The language definition says that this produces undefined behavior. That's because it is sometimes not possible to diagnose it. Compilers that warn you about this kind of thing are occasionally wrong. I've added an unneeded return statement to silence one compiler, only to have another complain about that return statement as "unreachable code"

Answer (score 0):

I'm using g++ 9.3.0, so can't tell much about g++ 5.4

At older versions, if you have a C++ program missing a return statement from a function that is supposed to return a value, g++ will compile it happily with no errors (or even a warning, unless -Wreturn-type or -Wall or -Werror=return-type is used). Trying to use the return value from the function will most likely cause a segmentation fault.

If you want that behavior, use -Werror=return-type

Comment: That's only the case in C. In C++, as soon as you flow off a non-void function without returning a value, it's UB, even if you don't use the return value. In this case, there is a way to call foo without UB, by setting the badbit on `std::cout` and making it throw exceptions (so it would exit via the exception).